# can we write a script which could be usable to scrape multiple sites

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written almost 30 different scraping scripts for 30 different websites. A friend of mine told me that it is possible to have a single code file for scraping all these 30 websites and bring it to the dashboard for dynamic scraping (I didn't understand what he means). I know every single website has its own structure and different data is coming from different pages and elements. On the other hand, some websites provide dynamic data instead of static data which I used selenium for its scraping.

I am really not sure about what he was thinking and is it possible to follow a path where I right one single long script file and use it for scraping many websites.

I would appreciate it if anyone having knowledge about this help me with the idea, tutorials, web contents and...

Comment: There are tools like Newspaper which let you define a scraping function for sites with a particular structure, then scrape all sites which you have a scraping function for. Out of the box, like its name implies, Newspaper is for news sites, but the general principle should be obvious.

Comment: my scripts scrape websites that post business opportunities for small businesses. I am scrapping those for my business team so that they get aware of any opportunity posted from another organization. now like I said I have many scripts and each one is different from another. can you suggest to me some topics, technology, libraries ... I follow and search to understand more about this.

Comment: @DRPK yes dear, but I don't think we are on the same path. you are trying to tell me how to use the multiprocessing technique while scrapping( here we are still having our long list of scrappers)  but I am saying the scrapping script should be the same and much general which can be used for scrapping many websites. am I right?

Comment: You are talking about something like Software architecture ? Making Micro-Services ? or you wanna some technologies like Scrapy/Spider https://scrapy.org/ ? did you know about Scrapy? and also you can handle dynamic websites with Splash https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, splash can works with Scrapy; they made for big/massive web crawler apps even for production.

Comment: @DRPK , hey thank you for your comment, you look so supportive and I appreciate it. can I have your email so that I talk to you over there for more discussion.

Comment: Tnx YW; i updated my answer and added these few things. sure! but we need to find private way to sending our email; do you have any idea ?

Comment: @TalibDaryabi: i have mailed you, did you receive that ? if yes so remove your email address; because its possible to web crawlers (for big IT companies) crawling over nets and extracting these kind of info from websites then you may have too much spam emails in future.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you can;

1. Make module for each scraper
2. Make an main app
3. Import your modules to the main app
4. Scrape your target website by using [**multiprocessing**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [**multithreading**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) methods.

### Conceptual Code:

```
# This code will not run!

from multiprocessing import Pool
from Scrapers import Scraper1, Scraper2, Scraper3, ...


def run_each_scraper(get_scraper_object):
    get_scraper_object.run()

def launcher():
    list_of_websites = []
    # use loops here
    reserve_scraper_objects_for_websites = [Scraper1.scrape(list_of_websites[0]),
                                            Scraper2.scrape(list_of_websites[1]),
                                            ...]
    process_objects = Pool(20) # Depends on your system resource
    process_objects.map(run_each_scraper, reserve_scraper_objects_for_websites)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    launcher()
```

But if you need some technologies i suggest you to switch in [Scrapy/Spider](http://scrapy.org); Also you can handle dynamic websites with [Splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stabl), Splash can works with Scrapy. They made for big/massive web crawler apps even for production.

Comment: Multiprocessing and/or multithreading are useful if you need to run things in parallel, which probably eventually you'll probably need if you scale out to thousands of web sites; but for a few dozen, that's probably an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @tripleee yes you are right and there are many methods that we can do his job i just explained one of them, but about unnecessary complication you do not. Unlike many languages python is simple and its modules are simple too. python made for implementing high techs with few lines of code.